# Failing to detect WorkbookAddinInstall event in MS Excel + VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I do not seem to be able to detect the `WorkbookAddinInstall` event with Excel 2013.

I have created an Excel addin with a class module (called CExcelEvents) that has simple subroutine handlers for a number of events, as shown here

```
Private WithEvents XLApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set XLApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub XLApp_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "NewWorkbook" & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub XLApp_WorkbookAddinInstall(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "AddinInstall"
End Sub


Private Sub XLApp_WorkbookAddinUninstall(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "AddinUnInstall"
End Sub

Private Sub XLApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "OpenWorkbook" & Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Then in the `ThisWorkbook` module of my addin workbook I have

```
Private ExcelEvents As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ExcelEvents = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

All of these handlers work except for `XLApp_WorkbookAddinInstall`.

Can anyone see what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that any addins installed **after** my addin has been installed are detected, but the initial install is not signaled (which of course is what I want).

However, placing the following Subs in the ThisWorkbook module of the addin does give the behaviour I need:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    MsgBox "An addin is being installed"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AddinUninstall()
    MsgBox "An addin is being removed"
End Sub
```